# Bunifu Flat Button: Selected Property Problem (deselect itself)

Tags: bunifu

When I click the button the bt.selected = True works, but when I move my mouse cursor the button deselects.. what should i do?

I'm using Bunifu 1.5.3 and Devexpress Framework

```
      Private Sub btnNavi_Dashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNavi_Dashboard.Click, btnNavi_AddStudent.Click, btnNavi_Dept.Click, btnNavi_Sched.Click, btnNavi_StudentInfo.Click, btnNavi_ViewAcct.Click

          Dim bt As BunifuFlatButton = DirectCast(sender, BunifuFlatButton)
          bt.selected = True
      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the IsTab property to true

```
Private Sub btnNavi_Dashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNavi_Dashboard.Click, btnNavi_AddStudent.Click, btnNavi_Dept.Click, btnNavi_Sched.Click, btnNavi_StudentInfo.Click, btnNavi_ViewAcct.Click

          Dim bt As BunifuFlatButton = DirectCast(sender, BunifuFlatButton)
          bt.selected = True
          bt.isTab= True
      End Sub
```